# Resharper Auto Complete Statement

Tags: resharper

I know it's probably something easy, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Say I have the following code

```
string name;

name.LastIndexOf("aaa");
```

After I type the single quote Resharper will added another for me so I have

```
name.LastIndexOf("")
```

After I type aaa I have name.LastIndexOf("aaa|") but now my caret | is sitting inside the double quote...

How do I tell Resharper that I am done so it can add the ; and move to the next line without using the mouse or the direction key?

Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. Using the End key is not much different from the directional key. I was looking for a one step key stroke that will tell Resharper  to complete the statement and move to the next block. I think it certain possible since Resharper is so smart. I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can actually use the Complete Statement feature (which is mapped to Ctrl+Shift+Enter in ReSharper 2.x and IntelliJ IDEA keymap). This will put ';' at the end of the statement and move the caret to the next line

Answer (score 8):

You can type `")`, just as you would normally, or press the End key.

Answer (score 0):

At that point ReSharper isn't waiting for you to complete a template so you'll need to type `[End];` to move to the end of the line and complete the statement.